Windows Batch: Get file Path without overlaying folders from bat file
I want to list recursively files under a folder structure and read out the name and the path.
But not the fullpath, I want only the path between the bat and the file.
For Example:
C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\com\test\test.jar

Call the Bat in
C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\com

Result:
com\test\test.jar

I tried in my code to replace/remove the part of the path C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\ but it doesn't work:
@ECHO OFF
SET "StartPath=%cd%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%f in (*.jar) do (
  set fullpath=%%f
  echo "fullpath: !fullpath!"
  echo "name: %%~nxf"
  set jarpath=%!fullpath!:!StartPath!=%
  echo "jarpath: !jarpath!"
)

How can i get the path I want?
Thanks in advance

Do not create a variable named path, change that name to something that isn't already an important environment variable name. How do you 'call the bat'? Do you know that %cd% is not necessarily the location of the bat?

@Compo %cd% is returning me C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\ which is fine and what i want to remove out of the string. I changed the path variable as you said. The problem I have is, that instead of a replacing and removing it, it writes C:\Users\testuser\Downloads= in the path variable

Okay, let me put it another way, %cd% returns the current directory. What you want to use is the directory of the running batch file. The batch file itself is always assigned to a special variable, %0. You should therefore use that, with its modifers, to get the location you need and its parent directory name. It's no good trying to fix your reported issue until you have corrected your fundementals.

@Compo thanks, I changed it. I also managed to fix the issue and posted the final result as answer

Despite your own answer, this provides the code for the specific problem you laid out in your question.

For Example:
C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\com\test\test.jar

Call the Bat in
C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\com

Result:
com\test\test.jar


@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For %%G In ("%~dp0.") Do For /R "%~dp0." %%H In ("*.jar") Do (Set "FullPath=%%H"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo "fullpath: !FullPath!"& Echo "name: %%~nxH"
    For %%I In ("!FullPath:%%~fG=%%~nxG!") Do EndLocal & Echo "jarpath: %%~I"
) 

Pause

EndLocal
Exit /B


I Finally got the expected result for pushing jars generically to gitlab registry:
@ECHO OFF
REM Path of the bat file
SET "StartPath=%~dp0"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Find all files in current directory with the ending of jar
for /R %%f in (*.jar) do (
  REM Absolute Path of the file
  set "fullpath=%%f"    
  REM Removes the startpath from the absolute path
  set "fullpath=!fullpath:%StartPath%=!"
  REM Changes backward slashes to forward slashes
  set "fullpath=!fullpath:\=/!"
  echo "fullpath: !fullpath!"
  REM curl the jar to gitlab registry artifactory
  curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:12345" --upload-file !fullpath! "https://example.com/api/v4/projects/12345/packages/maven/!fullpath!" 
)


Thank you for changing every one of those invalid labels :: to Rem. Please get into the habit of always using Rem for remarks.

Just to clarify the main reasons for my answer. Your question didn't ask about removing "the startpath from the absolute path". You specifically showed it to still include the parent directory name of that batch file in the output.  Your question was completely unrelated to curl, uploading, or gitlab, and did not show any requirement to change backward slashes to forward slashes. You should also be aware that in your 'curl' command line you appear to be using !fullpath! unquoted, and I would advise against doing so.

Hm the question was about to remove the startpath and IT wasn' working. I Just added my final result, which wasnt completly finished before

To clarify, you were not removing %StartPath%. The task, as submitted, was to replace the absolute path of the batch file's parent, in the results, with just the name of that parent. Please note: batch file location C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\com, you wanted to remove the C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\ part only, not the C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\com. You showed the result of com\test\test.jar, not test\test.jar.
